# SWIFTUI Binding Not Updating

Tags: swiftui, binding, popover

I have a home screen with a “log in” button. Click the button, it will pops up a log in screen. Once it’s logged in, the popover screen will be dismissed. and the home screen will say “logged in!”  I have a `@State`  boolean var monitoring button click, and another `@EnvironmentObject`  observing login status. If log in succeeds, `isAnon=false` . Then the popover window will be dismissed. But it doesn’t work now. when logged in successfully, the popover screen is still on. I’m suspecting the statement `Binding<Bool>()`  doesn’t update when `isAnon=false` . is this possible ? where did I miss?  Thanks a lot! Here is the code

```
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @State var isSignInClicked: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if session.isAnon{// if it is anonymous
            Button("Please Sign in to view your activities") {
                isSignInClicked.toggle()
            }
            .popover(isPresented: Binding<Bool>( get: { session.isAnon && isSignInClicked},set: {_ in })){
                LogInView()
            }
        }
        else{// if it's logged in
            Text("Logged In!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your `isAnon` property is computable - that might be the reason, make instead it stored published property.

Comment: ```isAnon``` is a ```@Published```

Answer (score 1):

as @Asperi mentioned, use a `@Published` for `isAnon`. This works well for me.
Here is my test code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var session = SessionStore()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView().environmentObject(session)
        }
    }
}  
    
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isAnon = true
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @State var isSignInClicked: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if session.isAnon {// if it is anonymous
            Button("Please Sign in to view your activities") {
                isSignInClicked.toggle()
            }
            .popover(isPresented: Binding<Bool>( get: { session.isAnon && isSignInClicked},set: {_ in })){
                LogInView()
            }
        }
        else {// if it's logged in
            Text("Logged In!")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT1: include the missing test `LoginView`

```
struct LogInView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("LogInView here")
            .onDisappear {
                session.isAnon = false
            }
        // alternative using a button
        //        Button("LogInView click me") {
        //            session.isAnon = false
        //        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @workingdog. But my ```isAnon``` is defined the way same as you do. The problem is that, the popover doesn't dismiss. In your code, how the popover will be dismissed? ```isAnon``` doesn't change, right?  In my code, when log in succeeds, ```isAnon``` is set to ```false```, which is supposed to dismiss the popover. I printed out the value of ```isAnon``` after log in. It did change to ```false```. However, I don't know how to print out the value of ```Binding<Bool> ()```

Comment: Now my guess is that, since the ```Button``` is also controlled by ```session.isAnon```. When ```session.isAnon``` is set to ```false ```, SWIFTUI destroys ```Button``` first. Since the popover is attached to ```Button```, the command chain just gets lost. Is this possible?

Comment: I just delete the ```if session.isAnon```, the popover is dismissed as it's supposed. Any suggestion for implementing this scenario: Click a button on homepage to show a sign in window; when sign in completed, the sign in window is dismissed and homepage shows new content.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my test `LogInView`. Updated my answer with it. Let me know if that does not work for you.